# Conditional method invocation from strings

Tags: c#, methods, runtime

I have a class (MethodsClass) with methods signature:

```
public double Method()
```

And a `DataGrid` with `ComboBoxColumn`. The ComboBox has the names of all methods of MethodsClass.

At runtime I need to invoke the method chosen from ComboBox. I am not very good with reflection and I know it is slow. Can I create an instance of MethodsClass using an ordinary initialisation

```
var mClass = new MethodsClass();
```

and then somehow invoke the method I need using a string from ComboBox. If not - what is the best way to implement the task.

Comment: You need either reflection or a dictionary of delegates (faster & safer)

Comment: I think dictionary of delegates will suit me better because then I won't be tied up to the same method signature. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a `Dictionary<string, Action<...>>` containing delegates (either method names or lambda expressions) to execute for each string value.

This is much faster than reflection, and also allows you to decouple the string values and parameters from the method signatures.

Comment: +1 though reading the OP's comment, it sounds more like he was ordering the code off a menu.

Comment: Honestly, this is my first year in writing code after reading 4 thick books. I have a little mess in my head after learning so much. I just need somebody to point me in the right direction and I will keep digging the same books untill I get it. Thank you all for your help.